# i Can not save the foreign key in Spring mvc form select tag

Tags: spring, model-view-controller

I'm trying to save a form that has a foreign key in select tag but it's always null. !

class user :

```
@Entity
public class User implements Serializable{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long UserCode;
    private String Lastname;
    private String Firstname;
    private String Adress;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="CityCode")
    private City CityCode;
    private String phone;
    private String mail;
    private int newsletter;
```

controller :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/add", method = RequestMethod.POST)
        public String add(@ModelAttribute("userModel") User user,BindingResult bindingResult, Model model) {    
            user.setCreator("admin");
            user.setDateCreation(new Date());
            user.setDateChange(new Date());

            model.addAttribute("user", new User());
            metier.AddUser(user);

            return "redirect:/user";
        }
```

code html :

```
<div class="form-group">
<label for="city" class="control-label col-lg-2">Ville</label>
  <div class="col-lg-4">
     <f:select path="CityCode" class="control-label col-lg-12">
        <c:forEach items="${states}" var="state">
            <option value="${state.cityCode }">${state.name }</option>                                                  
        </c:forEach>
    </f:select>
</div>
```

i cant save city code in table user

Answer (score 0):

I think you miss CascadeType:

`@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)`

more details here : https://dzone.com/tutorials/java/hibernate/hibernate-example/hibernate-mapping-many-to-one-using-annotations-1.html

Comment: i have this error : Field error in object 'userModel' on field 'CityCode': rejected value [1];   i cant save value 1 in citycode with type city !!

Comment: You are sure that the value="${state.cityCode }" is a City object?

Comment: The value="${state}" is a City object? If yes try to change value="${state}" Before saving the user you should have a valid & persisted object City in CityCode field. And I think you're confused by your annotation ... so a City object should have a cityCode ( and a cityName, county and so on ) and in your c:forEach option value you pass the cityCode ( wich is only one field in the object)